# Formatting yaml block text for use in an ansible assert test

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to write a fairly simply unittest for an ansible task.  Here is the basic task:

```yaml
---
- name: Test task
  host: localhost
  task:
    - name: My test task
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
      dest: /my_output.yaml
      block: |
        thing 1
        thing 2
        thing 3
     register: output

- name: Test output
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that:
      - output.changed == true
      - output.block: |                   <-- Problem line
          # BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
          thing 1
            thing 2
              thing 3
          # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

I can confirm that the output to the `my_output.yaml` does in fact match the block text per the assert, including the spacing on `thing 2` and `thing 3`.  However this assertion does not actually run during the test.  Obviously, the test isn't currently setup to actually test for `==`.

If I use `- output.block == |` the formatted block text doesn't work.  I can also use spacing and `\n` to represent the formatted text and that does work using `- output.block == "# BEGIN AN...MANAGED BLOCK"` but it is very difficult to read.

**Is there a way to use block in this context?**

NOTE...  I know that I can use something like this as a separate assert, but it is multiple files and more difficult to 'read'.

```
- name: Compare output
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that:
      - lookup('file', '/my_output.yaml') == lookup('file', '/my_output_verified.yaml')
```

Comment: Just a small beautify thingy: you can write `output.changed` as is. You don't need to put `== true` behind it, as Python by nature is truthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion in the above. The pipe sign (`|`) is a yaml construct for [yaml multiline strings](https://yaml-multiline.info/). But you are using it inside an `assert` expression which is by definition a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces (see [`assert` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#parameter-that) and [basic conditional `when:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when). Moreover, your second condition is actually not using any test.

So to achieve your above test with the ease of use of a yaml scalar block, you need to assign the value to a variable and use that variable in your test. Something like the following should do (untested as I don't have an example file nor an output of your registered variable)

```yaml
- name: Test output
  vars:
    compare: |
      # BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
      thing 1
        thing 2
          thing 3
      # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that:
      - output.changed | bool
      - output.block == compare
```

This should put you on track for your direct problem.

Now to go further, the real question is: **why are you doing this at all?** The `blockinfile` module is (as the vast majority of Ansible modules) fully idempotent and will report `changed` if it modified something or `ok` if the content is already aligned. So **the `blockinfile` task is already your test** as in any case the content will be the one you passed for the block content.

Comment: The use case is for patching k8s configuration files on a home network.  After pushing a configuration change that was poorly formatted, I'm trying to catch those errors a little earlier.  The configuration file is heavily populated by ansible vault variables.

Comment: This worked very well and is very readable.  The only change I had to make is in not using the output from the Test task directly, but rather loading the `my_output.yaml` directly and adding a `\n` at the end.  Here: `my_output_yaml: "{{ lookup('file', '/my_output.yaml') | regex_replace('$', '\n') }}"`

Comment: It looks to me you rather need to use the [`validate` module option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-validate). I'm sure there's a kubectl command you can pass in there which will validate the patch prior to applying it.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, put the block into a variable

```yaml
    block: |-
      thing 1
      thing 2
      thing 3
```

and create the reference block too

```yaml
    begin: '# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK'
    end: '# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK'
    block_test: |-
       {{ begin }}
       {{ block }}
       {{ end }}
```

Create the file and register the result

```yaml
    - blockinfile:
        create: true
        dest: /tmp/my_output.yaml
        block: "{{ block }}"
      register: output
```

The registered output doesn't comprise the changed block

```yaml
  output:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3
    changed: true
    diff:
    - after: ''
      after_header: /tmp/my_output.yaml (content)
      before: ''
      before_header: /tmp/my_output.yaml (content)
    - after_header: /tmp/my_output.yaml (file attributes)
      before_header: /tmp/my_output.yaml (file attributes)
    failed: false
    msg: File created
```

You can get it from the file if you want to check the changes on your own

```yaml
    - command: "sed -n '/{{ begin }}/,/{{ end }}/p' /tmp/my_output.yaml"
      register: output_test
```

gives

```yaml
  output_test:
    stdout: |-
      # BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
      thing 1
      thing 2
      thing 3
      # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Now, you can compare the changes

```yaml
    - assert:
        that:
          - block_test == output_test.stdout
      when: output.changed
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: All assertions passed
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    block: |-
      thing 1
      thing 2
      thing 3

    begin: '# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK'
    end: '# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK'
    block_test: |-
       {{ begin }}
       {{ block }}
       {{ end }}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: block
    - debug:
        var: block_test

    - blockinfile:
        create: true
        dest: /tmp/my_output.yaml
        block: "{{ block }}"
      register: output

    - debug:
        var: output

    - command: "sed -n '/{{ begin }}/,/{{ end }}/p' /tmp/my_output.yaml"
      register: output_test

    - debug:
        var: output_test

    - assert:
        that:
          - block_test == output_test.stdout
      when: output.changed
```